# Having an issue in gulp

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, node-modules

```
const MAX_ARRAY_INDEX = 2 ** 53 - 1;

SyntaxError: Unexpected token *
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:549:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> 
\node_modules\@jonkemp\package-utils\lib\index.js:5:21
```

`node -v 6.17.1`
`npm -v 3.10.10`

```
gulp.task('js', function () {
    var js_src_files = [
        // './node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
        './node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.min.js',
        './node_modules/cropperjs/dist/cropper.min.js',
        './node_modules/jquery-lazy/jquery.lazy.min.js',
        './node_modules/handlebars/dist/handlebars.js',
        './node_modules/corejs-typeahead/dist/typeahead.bundle.js',
        // './node_modules/@fancyapps/fancybox/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.js',
        './node_modules/autosize/dist/autosize.min.js',
        './node_modules/timeago.js/dist/timeago.min.js',
        './static_resources/js/*'
    ];

        gulp.src(js_src_files)
        .pipe(concat('app.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./static_public/js'));
});
```

When i run the specific gulp task created in my `gulp.js` file, I get the above error, I am not able to resolve it and cant change node or npm versions.

Please help in the above situation

Comment: Are you trying to minimize a file?  You should show your gulpfile.js.

Comment: @Mark added, please check. I don't think there is some issue with gulp task.

Comment: And when you run just only the `js` task you get that error?  Are you using `gulp-uglify` when you get that error?

Answer (score 0):

No worries, I fixed it. Removed all `node_modules` and rebuild it :) thanx @Mark